# Can 'races', and 'ares' be a synonym for 'emergency'?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

The context for 'emergency' tag is as follows

> This tag is for questions about the use of amateur radio in support of public safety or disaster relief in a declared emergency, including any equipment, protocols, or techniques that are specifically applicable to emergency communications

Under 'emergency' there may be different protocol (is that the correct word?) depending upon which nation one looks at. The US uses both RACES, and ARES; the scope for each is different ... yet both apply to amateur radio in public service.

- Can 'races', and 'ares' be made a synonym for 'emergency'?
- What about any other similar protocol for which a tag is created in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tag synonyms should not be used to collapse specific terms into general ones. There is benefit to having both general and specific terms.

For instance, someone might be looking for information specifically about RACES. Having the [races](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races) tag makes it easy for them to browse through available information.

Similarly, someone might be looking for all information about emergency communications, in which case they can browse the [emergency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency) tag.

Synonyms should only be used for tags with *equivalent* meanings. It's okay to have multiple tags with slightly different meanings; if a post applies to more than one of them, one can simply apply all of the relevant tags.

For example, a question about RACES emergency procedures can be tagged [emergency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency)[races](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races).

Answer (score 4):

I think there is use for protocol specific tags like ares, races, vapepa, etc. etc. In some countries the protocols are different and specific questions require specific answers and tags.

A question can be about a single protocol like ARES and should be tagged as such. General emergency questions can be tagged "emergency".

Answer (score 2):

No.

ARES groups can volunteer for non-emergency public service events, so that is not just an "emergency" topic.

ARES and RACES are both US-only, so are unrelated to emergency services in other countries.

Individuals can be prepared for emergencies without belonging to ARES or RACES.

Comment: This was the answer I was going to add. +1.

Comment: There are other VOADs (Volunteer Agencies Active in Disaster) stateside, such as the American Red Cross and SATRN (the Salvation Army hams) plus paramilitary organizations like the Civil Air Patrol, USCG Auxiliary, and the Military Amateur Radio Services. Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_amateur_radio_organizations has a large list of other organizations, in the US and elsewhere. Therefore, I concur that _emergency_ is a valid tag separate and apart from those VOADs and other organizations cited above.   

John Bartley K7AAY

Answer (score 1):

We should have multiple distinct tags: [races](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races) [ares](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ares) [emergency](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency).

If someone googles for one of the words (RACES/ARES) then having that tag, on the question, will help the question be found.